# How do I fix this 'MODULE NOT FOUND ERROR' with TWEEPY?

Tags: python, twitter, oauth, nlp, tweepy

I'm trying to register my application to retrieve tweets from Twitter's API. But I keep getting this 'MODULE NOT FOUND ERROR'. What is wrong with my code?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `.py` when importing. `import credentials` should work

Answer (score 0):

Use `import credentials` and also check the file name you are importing.
For twitter sentiment analysis,some importing libraries you have to import are-

```
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
import datetime, time
```

Recheck these things and it will work :)